# Accessing a GCE Windows Sever 2019 VM from the browser using its IP address

Tags: http, https, file-sharing, windows-server-2019

I have a Compute Engine instance running a Windows Server 2019 OS which has SAGE Premium 2020 installed. I am trying to access the files and folders of this server through `HTTP` and `HTTPS` from the browser.

Sadly I am a layman when it comes to all this. What I want to achieve is to be able to go to the server's IP address (which I have made static) from the browser, i.e. `12.34.56.79` and to be able to log in and access the `C:\` drive so I can have access to the contents of the drive.

Any help in getting this done will be 100% appreciated.

Comment: What you want to accomplish is not possible in that way, and wouldn't be very advisable. You could access your files via RDP though. cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#winrdp 
Would this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but RDP wouldn't work, An API requires access to the SAGE installation in the Compute Engine Instance. It needs to be able to access the folder through http or https. I have seen cases of where people access severs through http on the cloud

Comment: Do you have any reference to the documentation about the access for the API you could provide? This would be useful to understand what exactly are your needs in this case. Also, if you have a link or screenshot of how any of the cases you mention look like.